# How does max_bin param affect the speed and overfitting of LightGBM?

Tags: machine-learning, lightgbm

This is from lightgbm doc[image]
But I still don't understand what is bin? and how it is affecting the performance of lightgbm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key part of LightGBM is that it bins continuous features into bins/buckets (like a histogram) when building trees, which reduces memory use and massively speeds up training time. See section 4.1 of the docs, [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/lightgbm/latest/lightgbm.pdf).

XGBoost has now implemented this as an option too, which allows similar training speeds as LightGBM and can be implemented using `tree_method='hist'`.

Answer (score -1):

My recent experience with using `max_bin` (`max_bin: 500`) was that it gives issues in GPU mode. So when running in GPU mode I skip this param.

I see the docs say use `63`, why not `64`? And what's the highest we can use without running into issues in GPU mode?